# C# - Linq to combine (or) join two datatables into one

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I'm having problem in getting correct data from two datatables into one by using Linq in C#.
 
My datatables' data are coming from Excel file reading (not from DB). 
 
I have tried below linq but return rows count is not what I want (my goal is to retrieve all data but for verification, I'm checking on row count so that I can know is it correct or not easily).  
In dt1, I have 2645 records. 
In dt2, I have 2600 records. 
 
Return row count is 2600 (it looks like it is doing right join logic).

```
var v1 = from d1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
         from d2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(x => x.Field<string>(X_ITEM_CODE) == d1.Field<string>(X_NO) 
         || x.Field<string>(X_ITEM_KEY) == d1.Field<string>(X_NO))
         select dt1.LoadDataRow(new object[] 
         { 
             // I use short cut way instead of Field<string> for testing purpose.
             d1[X_NO],
             d2[X_ITEM_CODE] == null ? "" : d2[X_ITEM_CODE] ,
             d2[X_ITEM_KEY] == null ? "" : d2[X_ITEM_KEY],
             d2[X_COSTS],
             d2[X_DESC],
             d2[X_QTY]== null ? 0 : dt[X_QTY]
         }, false);

         dt1 = v1.CopyToDataTable();
         Console.WriteLine(dt1.Rows.Count);
```

I tried to use 'join' but my problem is the X_NO value can be either in X_ITEM_CODE or X_ITEM_KEY, so I can only put one condition in ON xxx equals yyy. 
 
I would like to try 'join' if my above condition is suitable to use too. Please provide me some guide. Thanks.

[Additional Info]
I already tried foreach loop + dt1.Select(xxxx) + dt1.Rows.Add(xxx), it is working well but with around 2 minutes to complete the job.
I'm looking for a faster way and from above Linq code I tried, it seems faster than my foreach looping so I want to give Linq a chance. 
For demo purpose, I only put a few columns in above example, my actual column count is 12 columns. 
 
I afraid my post will become very long if I put on my foreach loop so I skip it when I post this question. 
Anyway, below is the code and sample data. For those who can edit and think it is too long, kindly take out unnecessary/unrelated code or lines.

```
DataRow[] drs = null;
DataRow drO = null;

foreach (DataRow drY in dt2.Rows)
{
    drs = null;
    drs = dt1.Select(X_NO + "='" + drY[X_ITEM_KEY] + "' OR " + X_NO + "='" + drY[X_ITEM_CODE] + "'");
    if (drs.Length >= 0)
    {
        // drs Leng will always 1 because no duplicate.
        drs[0][X_ITEM_CODE] = drY[X_ITEM_CODE];
        drs[0][X_ITEM_KEY] = drY[X_ITEM_KEY];
        drs[0][X_COST] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_COST]);      // If null, return 0.
        drs[0][X_DESC] = clsD.GetStr(drY[X_DESC]);      // If null, return "".
        drs[0][X_QTY] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_QTY]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not Found in ITEM CODE or KEY, add it.
        drO = dtOutput.NewRow();
        drO[X_ITEM_CODE] = drY[X_ITEM_CODE];
        drO[X_ITEM_KEY] = drY[X_ITEM_KEY];
        drO[X_COST] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_COST]);
        drO[X_DESC] = clsD.GetStr(drY[X_DESC]);
        drO[X_QTY] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_QTY]);
        dt1.Rows.Add(drO);
    }
}
// Note: For above else condition, I didn't put in my Linq testing yet.
// If without else condition, my dt1 will still have same record count.
```

[dt1 data]
X_NO,X_ITEM_CODE,X_ITEM_KEY,COST,DESC,QTY,....
AA060210A,,,,,,....
AB060220A,,,,,....
AC060230A,,,,,....
AD060240A,,,,,....

[dt2 data]
X_ITEM_CODE,X_ITEM_KEY,COST,DESC,QTY
AA060210A,AA060211A,100.00,PART1,10000
AB060221A,AB060220A,120.00,PART2,500
AC060232A,AC060230A,150.00,PART3,100
AD060240A,AD060243A,4.50,PART4,15250

[Update 2] 
I tried below 'join' and it return nothing. So, can I assume join also will not help?

```
var vTemp1 = from d1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             join d2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
             on 1 equals 1
             where (d1[X_NO] == d2[X_ITEM_CODE] || d1[X_NO] == d2[X_ITEM_KEY])
             select dt1.LoadDataRow(new object[] 
             { 
                d1[X_NO],
                d2[X_ITEM_CODE] == null ? "" : d2[X_ITEM_CODE] ,
                d2[X_ITEM_KEY] == null ? "" : d2[X_ITEM_KEY],
                d2[X_COST],
                d2[X_DESC],
                d2[X_QTY]== null ? 0 : d2[X_QTY]
             }, false);

Console.WriteLine(vTemp1.Count()); // return zero.
```

Comment: Provide some sample data or output and if possible, show the query with foreach loop.

Comment: What really are you trying to achieve? The above is not a pure LINQ query because `LoadDataRow` has side effect of modifying one of the tables used in the query. Also the query is basically a LINQ equivalent of a nested `forach` loop, so the performance will not be better. Can you post your working non LINQ code?

Comment: @AT-2016, sorry for lack of info. I have modified to include foreach loop.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I put that LoadDataRow is for me to easily get back to DataTable. That above linq is my testing code only. If possible, I prefer 'join' but like I mentioned due to my OR condition I cannot use 'join'. I'm trying to get all records from dt1 while adding in dt2 column data into dt1 by matching three columns values with 'OR' conditions.

Comment: if you want to join two tables then use the `join` keyword

Comment: @Radinator, I would like to use 'join' too but I have OR condition so 'ON xx equals yy' join statement, it already fail my OR condition.

Comment: LINQ supports only equijoins, so we understand you cannot use join. Is `X_NO` field in `dt1` unique?

Comment: @IvanStoev, yes, X_NO is unique in dt1. In my foreach example, I do not need to check for the length, it is because it is unique. (FYI: I already did a Group linq to get unique X_NO for dt1) after I read the data from excel file.

Comment: Not using join is perfectly fine. So leave that behind you. The only thing is, as mentioned above, that you modify `dt1` in your query. It's better to create a collection of datarows first and then add these to the datatable.

Comment: @GertArnold, thanks for the tips. Now, I see previously Ivan also mentioned about it and I didn't notice it. I think my choice is to use foreach with collection or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ supports only *equijoins*, so apparently `join` operator cannot be used. But using LINQ query with Cartesian product and `where` will not give you any performance improvement.

What you really need (being LINQ or not) is a fast lookup by `dt1[X_NO]` field. Since as you said it is unique, you can build and use a dictionary for that:

```
var dr1ByXNo = dt1.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(dr => dr.Field<string>(X_NO));
```

and then modify your process like this:

```
foreach (DataRow drY in dt2.Rows)
{
    if (dr1ByXNo.TryGetValue(drY.Field<string>(X_ITEM_KEY), out dr0) ||
        dr1ByXNo.TryGetValue(drY.Field<string>(X_ITEM_CODE), out dr0)) 
    {
        dr0[X_ITEM_CODE] = drY[X_ITEM_CODE];
        dr0[X_ITEM_KEY] = drY[X_ITEM_KEY];
        dr0[X_COST] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_COST]);      // If null, return 0.
        dr0[X_DESC] = clsD.GetStr(drY[X_DESC]);      // If null, return "".
        dr0[X_QTY] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_QTY]);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not Found in ITEM CODE or KEY, add it.
        drO = dtOutput.NewRow();
        drO[X_ITEM_CODE] = drY[X_ITEM_CODE];
        drO[X_ITEM_KEY] = drY[X_ITEM_KEY];
        drO[X_COST] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_COST]);
        drO[X_DESC] = clsD.GetStr(drY[X_DESC]);
        drO[X_QTY] = clsD.GetInt(drY[X_QTY]);
        dt1.Rows.Add(drO);
    }
}
```

Since you are adding new records to the `dt1` during the process, depending of your requirements you might need to add at the end of the `else` (after `dt1.Rows.Add(drO);` line) the following

```
dr1ByXNo.Add(dr0.Field<string>(X_NO), dr0);
```

I didn't include it because I don't see your code setting the new record X_NO field, so the above will produce duplicate key exception.

Comment: thanks for the sample code and tips. I will try with the code. For me, I need to use var vDict = dt1.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(dr => dr.Field<string>("")); . May be because I'm not follow MVVM pattern?

Comment: I have tested and your method is way faster than my dt.Select method. Now, it becomes a few seconds only. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are right for `AsEnumerable()`, I just missed that, will correct the answer, thank you.